# Internal SSD disconnects from laptop motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, motherboard, lenovo-laptop

Recently my Lenovo Ideapad Flex 15 laptop's internal SSHD broke, so with some help I replaced it and reinstall Windows 8.1 and everything else. Now the laptop works normally, except that sometimes the SSD disconnects (at least that's what I think is happening). Then at startup it says "Checking media..." followed by "EFI Network 0 for IPv4 boot failed." If I'm working on the laptop, the screen goes blue and Windows tries to run some diagnosis tool and fail and reboots to the "boot failed" screen.

I'm able to fix the problem for a bit until it happens again, by opening the laptop and disconnecting and reconnecting the data cable that runs from the hard drive port to the motherboard. I think either something is wrong with the cable or the hard drive cable slot on the motherboard is somewhat loose.

I really want to fix this problem permanently but I'm not sure how. Can it be repaired by simply adding something to the cable slot on the motherboard to keep the cable in place or would it require something bigger like replacing the motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to do these checks step-by-step, but first just to confirm: I suspect what is happening is the HDD is disconnecting and resulting in the machine just re-booting itself, this then results in Windows corruption on your drive which luckily you seem to be resolving via Windows restore/repair.

To be cost effective, I'd definitely recommend trying a different SATA cable, and if your Power supply Unit (PSU) has any spare cables, try one of these as well.

Just to confirm, how frequently are you getting these power-cuts?